# Cursor на объекте

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте!
Снова проблемы...
На странице поместил

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tuda.d9x.ru/styles/Main_Style.css" type="text/css">
```

В стайле есть описание компонента

```
    .menuCell
    {
        font-weight: bold;

        CURSOR: hand;
    }
```

Проблема в том что курсор не становится в форме руки при наведении на компонент

```
    <DIV class="menuCell"> tratata   </DIV>
```

Подскажите что делать пожалуйста. может ошибка кода?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

кроссбраузерно: "cursor: pointer;"

Comment: я бы даже сказал
<pre>cursor: pointer !important;
cursor: hand;</pre>

Comment: Можно пояснить последний код?

Comment: А important нафига?

Comment: и вправду зачем !important?
cursor:pointer +1

Comment: important - это не чтобы писька, пардон, отвисла, а обозначает, что это свойство обрабатывать с приоритетом

Comment: Мы вроде спрашиваем, зачем он тут, а не что это такое.

Comment: Получается что есть возможность игнорирования кода?